# CSS 3 box-shadow all around

Tags: css

I have this site here:

http://artendijen.com/susan_dev/

and I have a box-shadow around my nav box, I am looking to have the shadow a bit smaller, a color that looks more like a shadow and all around, except for the left side, just the top, bottom, and right side. Is this possible?

```
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #000;
```

Comment: Just dont move the shadow if you want it all around; and use a transparent color for a more realistic color: `box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of the box-shadow is like this (ignoring `inset` and `spread`):

```
box-shadow: <offset-x> <offset-y> <size> <color>;
```

So to have the shadow smaller, decrease the size. 
To have the shadow at a different position, change the offsets.
For a more realistic color try a more transparent color.

This for example would give a result like you want it:

```
box-shadow: 5px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
```